# setting datacontext through Xml instead of DBML file..?

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-sql

How to set datacontext class through just -

> XML file

not as

> DBML file

.??

Scenario: Has a DBML file with DataContext defined in it.By Specifying the Connection string am accessing one table to ITable object?

AIM : Instead of this DBML file - can i use some XML file file to define the DataContext

Answer (score 1):

Are you refering to using the XMLMappingSource? If so, see http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/LINQ-to-SQL-support-for-POCO.aspx.

Comment: will it be possible to make mapping by Xml to Itable...!!??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do at this point. Could you give more information or pseudocode in your question?